# ngRoute + ngAnimate, animations skip the first time but work fine after that

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate, ngroute

I'm working on a revamp of my portfolio site and I'm using angular to handle routing. I've hooked up ngAnimate as well and as far as I can tell everything is working as expected. The only annoyance I've come across is that when navigating to a new page the first time, the animations do not seem to fire properly. After navigating to a page once, they work as expected. (I know the animations are a little over the top but I'm just experimenting with them).

I haven't been able to find the cause or a solution, but you can view the site at:

http://dev.jamesmyers.me/

Sorry if most of the pages are incomplete, I'm still working on it.